# django django-cities-light nothing displaying with middle east country

Tags: python, django

I am taking a project with Django, that use GeoIP and django-cities-light.

We use it for a showroom page where project has location.

So you can filter those project by categories or by region.

North America, Asia, Europe..

And it's working well !

But the thing is, I am asked to add Middle East region.

This the code in my views.py from the showroom application :

```
class CategoriesRegionsFilterForm(forms.Form):
REGIONS_CHOICES = (
    ('EU', _('Europe')),
    ('NA', _('North America')),
    ('AS', _('Asia')),
    ('SA', _('South America')),
    ('AF', _('Africa')),
    ('OC', _('Oceania')),
    ('ME', _('Middle East')),
)

categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label=_('Categories'),
                                       required=False,
                                       widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
regions = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label=_('Regions'),
                                    required=False,
                                    widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                    choices=REGIONS_CHOICES)
first_object = forms.IntegerField(required=False, initial=0)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(CategoriesRegionsFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    categories_qs = ProjectCategory.objects.active_translations(get_language())
    self.fields['categories'].choices = [(category.pk, category.name)
                                         for category in categories_qs]
```

As you can see, I simply added Middle East. It seems that there are no more treatment about it.

But on the website, what happen is :
When I create a test-project, in Iran -for example- it will be displayed as Asia region. And never show up in Middle East.

If I choose Egypt for this project, it will be displayed as Africa region filter.

But it won't show up in Middle East.

And in my model.py, here are the line managing the region filter creation :

```
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Country, verbose_name=_('Country of the project'),
                                 blank=True, null=True,
                                 related_name='regions_showroom_project')
```

So it seems that I might should add by hand which country are in Middle East ?

But it would be curious since django-cities-light data is pulled from GeoNames. And GeoNames seems to recognise Middle East.

Does anyone has a clue about it ? I am definitely lost here.

Comment: use `./manage.py cities_light` to , populate your database. maybe the problem is your own database.

Comment: Yeah I did it.. But it's not changing the fact that Iran is in Asian and not part of middle east for the module :(

Comment: But when I check GeoNames I figured out that Middle East exist but is empty. Compare to europ or America.